# Webcam Chat via Flash

Tags: flash

I'd like to do a bit of research on how to create a webcam chat web application. I've seen Flash do this. What is this technology called and where can I go to find out more about it? Also, any issues I need to be concerned about (e.g. server requirements, etc.)? Are there any other viable solutions other than Flash?

Comment: This will help you: http://www.flashrealtime.com/tutorial-multicast-streaming-in-flash-player-101/ Zsombor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you to get some concept,

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0DdrMNVn-vw&feature=related

Good Luck!